# Array ismember tilde

Tags: arrays, matlab, tilde

What does the tilde in the following code mean?

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6];
b = [5, 9, 6];
[~,c] = ismember(b,a);
```

If I do not use the tilde I just get a 1x3 logical array whereas with the tilde I get the array. But what exactly does ~ do?

Comment: The tilde `~` ignores the output where it is placed at. So in your code, the first output of `ismember` is ignored and the second output is assigned to `c`.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. But why does it generate 2 outputs anyway? What is the first and what is the second (the second is probably my array I want).

Comment: The first output is a logical array holding true (1) for the elements of `A` that are member of `B`, false (0) otherwise. The second output holds the locations (in `B`) of the first occurrences of the members. Look [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#btcnv44-11) for an example.

Comment: Very well explained. Got it now! Thanks!